Stripe Payment Problem about The PaymentIntent requires a payment method
I am developing an e-commerce solution having Blazor WASM for the client, Blazor Server for the admin, and API for CRUD and payment operations. I am using the latest (44.9) version of Stripe via a test account.
The problem is I am getting this error after clicking the pay button.

Here is the test dashboard of Stripe:

I did some research and came across this stripe-hosted page documentation. Stripe Hosted The difference is I am using PriceData rather than Price ID. Here is a Checkout Session creation endpoint example I ama following: Checkout Session
Here is my Stripe calling API:
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[ActionName("Create")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] StripePaymentDTO paymentDTO)
{
    try
    {
        var domain = _configuration.GetValue<string>("Client_URL");

        var options = new SessionCreateOptions
        {
            SuccessUrl = domain + paymentDTO.SuccessUrl,
            CancelUrl = domain + paymentDTO.CancelUrl,
            LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>(),
            Mode = "payment",
            PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string> { "card" }
        };

        foreach (var item in paymentDTO.Order.OrderDetails)
        {
            var sessionLineItem = new SessionLineItemOptions
            {
                PriceData = new SessionLineItemPriceDataOptions
                {
                    UnitAmount = (long)(item.Price * 100), //20.00 -> 2000
                    Currency = "USD",
                    ProductData = new SessionLineItemPriceDataProductDataOptions
                    {
                        Name = item.Product.Name
                    }
                },
                Quantity = item.Count
            };
            options.LineItems.Add(sessionLineItem);
        }

        var service = new SessionService();
        Session session = await service.CreateAsync(options);

        return Ok(new SuccessModelDTO()
        {
            Data = session.Id + ";" + session.PaymentIntentId
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(new ErrorModelDTO()
        {
            ErrorMessage = ex.Message
        });
    }
}

How can I fix this issue?
Edit 1:
Since I was using an older version of Stripe, I was not redirecting to the Session.url. Now I redirect it as follows;
Response.Headers.Add("Location", session.Url);
return new StatusCodeResult(303); 

I got this error;

The weird thing is I do not have localhost:53752 in my application

Stripe Checkouts expires after 24h by default, is this the case for that Checkout ?

I am having this issue when I make payment, how can it expire?

What are you redirecting to? Can you give us an sample link that gave you this result? If I recall, something like this can happen if the URL you're redirecting to is like the session URL but malformed in some way. I'm saying this because I don't see you clearly redirecting to the session.url

I was using an older version of Stripe which is why I am not redirecting to the session.url Now I changed to redirecting, and I got a Cross Origin Request Block  error. I added the browser console in the post. The weird thing is I do not have localhost:53752 in my application.

Weirdly, I am getting this when I try on Edge. On FF and Chrome, It seems working now.
